# Windows based shortsuts

Tags: pantheon-files, keyboard-shortcuts

I am new to eOS and I want to change from Windows to eOS. Therefore I trying this distro for a week now and change everything to guaranty my usual workflow.
Everything is working as expected for now and I found apps for all my tasks.

The only thing which is quite hard for me are the shortcuts for eOS.
Can I change the shortcuts of eOS to more Windows like behavior?

fe in Files -> backspace to go back
also the function keys are not working and I cannot assign only one key for any function

is there any additional tool or a config file for this changes ?

Every help is very much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'philosophy' of keyboard shortcuts of the elementary OS is quite different than the other OS, including Mac OS and Windows. You can change safely some of them using System Settings app > Keyboars > Shortcuts, also you can do this by using dconf editor, but if you are not experienced as it looks using dconf can cause you much more troubles than any achievements.

By using alt+arrow keys you can move backwards and forwards into your file navigaion history(alt + left and right arrows),folder above and inside(alt + up and down arrows) into your current file location.

Comment: The shortcuts work also in web browsers and some other apps btw - consistency y'know ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for being willing to try something new for and trying eOS! I do recommend you persevere with learning the new shortcuts where they differ from your old OS (although I understand that when you are using both OS's it may be a little confusing at first). They will quickly become second nature. If there is a function for which eOS does not currently provide any shortcut please feel free to raise an issue on for the appropriate project.  For Files that would be at https://github.com/elementary/files/issues.

As the previous answer states, you can add or change some shortcuts via the Settings panel, but not those that are internal to a specific application (that can only be done by raising an issue persuading the developers to amend the code).

Comment: There is an ongoing issue with making the app internal shortcuts sufficiently discoverable.  Some improvements have recently been made in exposing then in tooltips for example.  Press and release the "Windows" key to get a popup showing desktop shortcuts.